# How can I calculate cumulative percentage change from beginning period

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a `DataFrame` with a rolling cumulative percentage change. I would like to show the percentage change of the stock from the initial buy date (2014-09-05).

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as web

cvs = web.get_data_yahoo('cvs', '2014-09-05')['Adj Close']

cvsChange = cvs[1:] / cvs.shift(1) - 1
```

Comment: Isn't this just `cvs.diff().cumsum() * 100`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank you @EdChum

What I was looking for was...

```
PriceChange = cvs.diff().cumsum()
PercentageChange = PriceChange / cvs.iloc[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
(cvs.iloc[-1] - cvs.iloc[0]) / cvs.iloc[0] * 100
```

Comment: that works to find total change for the entire period (9/5/14 to today), but I am having difficulty with calculating the total percentage change at each period.

Comment: Please give your definition of a period in your question.  Is it monthly, quarterly, etc.?

Comment: My definition of a period is a single day.

Comment: Your question asks for the percentage change since 2014-09-05

Comment: With a rolling cumulative percentage change. Sorry for the confusion.