# Create new column inside loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the percentage change for value in `dftemp['eps_mean_est']` from the first value in that column.  I want to do that for each `dftemp['per_end_date']` within each stock.  Here's the code I have tried.  This is a pandas dataframe.

The error is

> KeyError: 'ticker'

.  What am I doing wrong?

```
dftemp.set_index(['ticker','per_end_date'], inplace=True)

for stock in dftemp['ticker'][0:]:
    for qtrDate in dftemp['per_end_date'][0:]:
        dftemp['pctchg'] = (dftemp['eps_mean_est'] - dftemp['eps_mean_est'][0]) /dftemp['eps_mean_est'][0]
```

Comment: `df['eps_mean_est'].pct_change()` ?

Comment: RafaelC, won't that create a pct change from the current row from the last row?  I am trying to create pct change from each row from the first row.

Comment: @RafaelC The error message included in the original post is not related to calculating the percentage. Therefore, it is not a dupe.

Comment: Column `dftemp['ticker']` does not exist in `dftemp` because you converted it into an index.

Comment: It is a dupe here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31950331/how-can-i-calculate-cumulative-percentage-change-from-beginning-period. The error comes from an XY problem, you don't need a loop for this